# How to generate python protobuf from java maven project

Tags: java, python, maven, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I have maven project in which I have defined various `.proto` files whose corresponding java files are generated through maven plugin. This generated files would be used for implementation [rpc - server implementation], but I want this to be consumed by python client.

Hence need python equivalent to these proto files.
One way is to manually run `python protobuf` command to these `.proto` files and generate code, but this would be too manual work. I am looking for some other alternative.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Worked by adding a goal as "compile-python" for protobuf-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1):

You could automate  your manual command b running it from Maven. Take a look at the [exec-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) plugin.

You need to add something like that to the plugins part of your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>Stuff I want done</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>path/stuff.sh</executable>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Adapt the [phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) and the script you want to run.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: need your help again. With my approach, the generated python code for rpc definition does not have stub definition. Please help, how to proceed further.

Comment: I have no idea. You should probably ask a new question for such a different need.

Comment: with your approach is the stub definition generated in python gen code ?

Comment: I don't know. My knowledge is on mainly on the Maven side. It should be generated exactly like it would be outside Maven by using the schellscript.

Answer (score 1):

Worked by adding execution goal as "compile-python" for protobuf-maven-plugin  ([link](https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/)) in pom file.

Comment: Thanks. But idea came after your answer